# My domain displaying ip instead of domain name

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, dns, magento2, cloudflare

I configured my virtual host to to the magento folder path but still it is still displaying the EIP (Elastic IP) of the ec2 instance, and connected it to cloud flare, but still no head.
visit the url http://alabamarket.com

Alabamarket.com.conf file located in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` folder

[image]

apache2.conf file located in the `/etc/apache2/` folder

[image]

The cloudflare dns

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no issue with DNS configuration. I think you need to update the base URL in Magento backend. To change base URL, login to your Magento admin area and navigate to:

Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Base URLs

and

Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Base URLs (secure)

Modify the base url input boxes and with your domain and click on Save Config.

The last step is to clear the cache of your Magento, under System -> Cache Management -> Flush Magento Cache.

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Invalid Base URL. Value must be a URL or one of placeholders: {{base_url}} when i added the domain name (http://alabamarket.com)

Comment: Can you try with full url with http (http : // alabamarket.com) Remove the spaces of course.

Comment: Thanks for the support, it is now working. We added the domain name only with the current config i posted earlier and did apache restart, we did not flush the cache though, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a checklist to help troubleshoot this issue:

**Step 1)** Go to your hosting provider and setup an A-Name record that points your Application servers IP Address (x.y.z.123) to your domain name (www.alabamarket.com)

**Step 2)** Check your VHOST configs to ensure that you've setup proper `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` values.

I've posted a screenshot of one of my vhost files here for your reference. 
[image: My Current Vhost setting]

*P.S:* Changes to conf files will require you to bounce Apache.

**Step 3)** Check your Magento instance's database to ensure that your base_url's are set to your domain and not an IP Address.
*Tip:* Typically if/when spinning up a pre-configured Magento VM - on most Cloud providers - the base_url's will be IP addresses.

```
select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url' ;
-- Expected result is `http://www.alabamarket.com/`

select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/secure/base_url';
-- Expected result is `https://www.alabamarket.com/`
```

If you need to change these values, you can do so via the Admin UIX (preferred-method) or directly in the DB (living-dangerously)

Navigation of change values via the Admin UIX: 
 - Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Base URLs
 - Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Base URLs (Secure)

Here's a screenshot of the values defined on one of my localhost instances:
[image: base_urls localhost]

**Step 4)** Clear all application caches (Follow the instructions for your specific cache - E.g: File System/Redis/etc)

**Step 5)** Attempt to access your domain `http://www.alabamarket.com/`

Let me know if I can assist any further.